# Netbeans PHP (Mac OSX) doesn't include full PHP Code Completion?

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, code-completion

I have just downloaded the Netbeans with PHP Bundle but when i run it, there is NO fully php code completion.

For very basic examples:

- `mysql_fetch_array`
- `substr`
- `explode`

It doesn't come up even with this basic funcions/methods/etc code completion inside PHP. **So what is the Netbeans with PHP Bundle for?** Why is it bundled as PHP, without even code completion as a basic need?

Anyone know how can i make it work?

Comment: What do you call **"full"** php code completion ? Care to share any example ? What did you expect ?

Comment: "FULL" means everything inside PHP (or PHP Manual). For very basic examples: `mysql_fetch_array` `substr` `explode` functions/methods etc in PHP even basically. *So what is the Netbeans with PHP Bundle for?*

Comment: Maybe some screenshot that shows that it is missing or sample code would be useful. This should work

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand your question. For example, for mysql_fetch_array, NetBeans IDE offers the code completion options mysql_fetch_array($result) and mysql_fetch_array($result, $result_type='MYSQL_BOTH'). For substr NetBeans offers substr($string, $start) and substr($string, $start, $length=null). What beyond this were you expecting?
Also, you might have more success posting at [NetBeans PHP Users Forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/php-users.html)